# Run python code in Excel

Tags: python, excel, package, analysis

I want to write python code to automate some excel procedures which I do on a daily basis and take me alot of time.

is there any package (or add-in in excel) I can use to run python code in excel?

Thanks!

Comment: would using libre/openoffice be an option? it uses python as its scripting language.

Answer (score 3):

**xlwings** will let you "Replace VBA macros with clean and powerful Python code."

See - https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/

Comment: Seems this is no more available

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

A google search of 'python excel' turns up this:

https://www.pyxll.com/

There are also some modules that allow you to manipulate excel files with python scripts, such as http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/, which may be an attractive alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without more info on exactly what you wish to do, but the [OpenPyXL](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) module for Python might be a good place to start.

As for running python directly in excel, I believe [XLWings](https://www.xlwings.org/) would be an option for you but, myself, I would rather just write a python script outside of Excel that takes the excel file as input and does whatever operations are needed using OpenPyXL (or some other module).

Comment: Hi, I basically want to do several simple actions in excel like sort data by date and time, generate pivot table etc...I know i can do these commands with VBA but i dont know this lang and its looks pretty complicated to learn so i prefer try the python option...